# Discord.py selfbot: How to delete the message right after sending?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I make it so when it sends the message where it tags everyone, it deletes the message right after?

Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MentionBomb:
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def mbomb(self, ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()

    messages = []
    msg = ""

    for member in ctx.message.channel.members:
        if len(msg) >= 1980:
            messages.append(msg)
            msg = ""

        msg += member.mention + "\n"

    if len(msg) >= 1:
        messages.append(msg)

    for message in messages:
        await ctx.send(message)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MentionBomb(bot))
```

Comment: Is `ctx` a `Client` object?  If you're using the old `discord.py`... `Client` should have methods called `delete_message` and `delete_messages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`send` returns an object representing the message it just sent.  That `Message` object has a `delete` coroutine.

```
for message in messages:
        sent = await ctx.send(message)
        await sent.delete()
```